# MQ Display channel status only without details

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to Display only the MQ channel ststua with out Details

When using CHSTATUS(KONDOR_TO_T24)

```
CHANNEL(KONDOR_TO_T24)                  CHLTYPE(SDR)
CONNAME(192.168.11.30(1414))            CURRENT
RQMNAME(GLOB_QM)                        STATUS(RUNNING)
SUBSTATE(MQGET)                         XMITQ(KONDOR_OUT)
```

it gives me all the bove details and i need only to display STATUS(RUNNING)

Answer (score 1):

That is the information you get when you issue the 'DISPLAY CHSTATUS' MQSC command.  If you want selective information from the command then write a script to parse out what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an old question but the answer will still be valid

Use the command runmqsc and pipe to awk

```
echo "DISPLAY CHS(KONDOR_TO_T24) STATUS"| runmqsc QMGR|grep STATUS|grep -v DISPLAY|awk -F"[()]" '(index($1,"STATUS") != 0) {print $2} (index($3,"STATUS") != 0) {print $4}'
```

- grep STATUS      gets all lines with STATUS
- grep -v DISPLAY  removes lines with DISPLAY, the actual command itself

  - *care here with the DESCR field does not contains the above info*
- awk -f "[()]" splits the lines removing the brackets to create 4 columns
- index($1,"STATUS") != 0) {print $2} checks column 1 for the word STATUS and prints column 2 value
- index($3,"STATUS") != 0) {print $4} checks column 3 for the word STATUS and prints column 4 value

Output will then be only the status of the CHS command, one of:

- **BINDING**

  - Channel is performing channel negotiation and is not yet ready to
    transfer messages.
- **INITIALIZING**

  - The channel initiator is attempting to start a channel.
- **PAUSED**

  - The channel is waiting for the message-retry interval to complete
    before retrying an MQPUT operation.
- **REQUESTING**

  - A local
    requester channel is requesting services from a remote MCA.
- **RETRYING**

  - A previous attempt to establish a connection has failed. The MCA will
    reattempt connection after the specified time interval.
- **RUNNING**

  - The channel is either transferring messages at this moment, or is waiting
    for messages to arrive on the transmission queue so that they can be
    transferred.
- **STARTING**

  - A request has been made to start the channel but the channel has not yet begun processing. A channel is in this state if it is waiting to become active.
- **STOPPED**

  - This state can be caused by one of the following:

    - Channel manually stopped

      - A user has entered a stop channel command against this channel.
    - Retry limit reached

      - The MCA has reached the limit of retry attempts at establishing a connection. No further attempt will be made to establish a connection automatically.
  - A channel in this state can be restarted only by issuing the START
    CHANNEL command, or starting the MCA program in an operating-system
    dependent manner.
- **STOPPING**

  - Channel is stopping or a close request has been received.
- **SWITCHING**

  - The channel is switching transmission queues